# How to set up mass executable file permission to all my scripts?

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems

**PROBLEM**

I have new servers and copied lot of files with these conditions:

- lot of files
- different suffix
- lost permissions
- among them there are other files

now I need to set up all and only executable file - check SOLUTION.

Comment: Try to reword this part "Q how can I set up all and only executable file?". With self posted answer one can guess what was the initial coal . But a new user would probably be confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

1. show files
2. filter only with shell script header
3. apply executable permission

`find /cnn -type f | xargs grep -rl '#!/bin/sh' | xargs chmod 755`

**Ref** thanks to: [WombleGoneBad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-to-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubunt), [Silver Moon](http://www.binarytides.com/linux-find-command-examples/), [Himanshu Arora](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/12/xargs-examples/)